# attempting to install forever via npm ... not working

Tags: bash, node.js, npm, forever

i am attempting to install forever using npm via shell command line:

```
npm install forever
```

this is the response i am getting:

```
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: /home/MYUSER/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! System Linux 3.1.9-vs2.3.2.5
npm ERR! command "/home/MYUSER/.nvm/v0.8.17/bin/node" "/home/MYUSER/.nvm/v0.8.17/bin/npm" "install" "forever"
npm ERR! cwd /home/MYUSER
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! file /home/MYUSER/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/MYUSER/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

i haven't had any trouble installing anything else via npm. why this?

---

actually, i needed to be in the npm directory!

Comment: It's highlighting that the issue is with `/home/MYUSER/package.json`. What are the contents on that file? Does it pass the stated requirement: "*package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.*" You can check it with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete downloaded module from `node_modules/forever` and install it again: `[sudo] npm install forever -g`, forever should be installed with `-g` (globally)